# Running multiple python scripts in parallel

Tags: python, bash, macos

To measure the processing time of a single versus 7 python scripts in parallel I perform the following test

I execute below code, named summer.py as a python script:

```
python3 summer.py
```

summer.py src:

```
import timeit

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
num = 100000000

sum = 0
while (num > 0):
    sum += num
    num -= 1
elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print("The sum is", sum)
print('elapsed is' , elapsed)
```

This script executes in 14 seconds, and therefore to run this script 7 times sequentially it would take approx 14 seconds * 7 = 98 seconds to complete.

Starting the script 7 times in parallel using the command :

```
nohup python3 summer.py > 1.txt &
nohup python3 summer.py > 2.txt &
nohup python3 summer.py > 3.txt &
nohup python3 summer.py > 4.txt &
nohup python3 summer.py > 5.txt &
nohup python3 summer.py > 6.txt &
nohup python3 summer.py > 7.txt &
```

I manually run each of the above commands, so it is a somewhat crude measure. Each script takes the following number of seconds to execute: 16,17,19,22,22,20,18. The time for all scripts to finish executing is 22 seconds, the max executing time of all scripts.

Running 7 instances of the program, sequentially takes approx 98 seconds while running in parallel from the command line takes 22 seconds. What parallelism is taking place that allows each process to run in parallel? As a new GIL created for each python process, this allows sharing the underlying CPU? If multiple cores are available on the CPU can/how each script be executed on a dedicated core to increase processing time?

Comment: Each python process gets it's own GIL, that's why the `multiprocessing` module is to popular

Comment: How many CPU cores do you have? Have a look at this [os.sched_setaffinity](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sched_setaffinity)

Comment: @PatrikPolakovic I have quad-core, do I need to explicitly inform python to use multiple cores or will the cores be shared when running multiple scripts in parallel automagically?

Comment: @blue-sky no you don't have to. OS will handle scheduling. However, you can still set processor affinity for particular process.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what the issue is. Why do you want to increase the processing time? Are you surprised that you can do 98s of processing in 22s on 4 cores - and if so, in a good way or a bad way?

Comment: quad-core, eh? I'd be interested in the timings when running 2 other tests ... 4 parallel copies of python code ... 3 parallel copies of python code (in case OS/other-processes are using a core's worth of processing); assuming little/no other processing on the host ... and really only have 4 cores ... I'd expect these new tests to run even faster (ie, I'd expect 7 concurrent runs to be a bit slower due to fighting for run time on 4 cores); next test would be to run 7-8 copies but only 4 at a time (ie, load balancing) to see if any benefits from reduced cpu contention